# Calculate BigInteger raised to negative power greater than 1 in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

How do I calculate β^-2 in Java where β is a BigInteger?

Comment: β^-2 is equal to 1/β^2

Comment: @SpiderPig so there's no existing function to perform that directly without implementing my own solution?

Comment: are you looking for `Math.pow()` function? This is seriously a bad question....

Comment: Once you start going into negative exponents, the result isn't an integer any more, so you need to look at BigDecimal...

Comment: @Sagar if you have worked with that fn you would know that it does not allow negative exponents

Comment: Also. the result wont be an integer because 1/x will most likely be a faction

Comment: @azurefrog is has to do with cryptography, so I think I will go with SpiderPig's custom solution.

Comment: It's not a big deal. Just do `BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(number).pow(2))`

Comment: Peter. I just did it online. I am not a java expert. but well.... that's what i did.

Comment: @SpiderPig That's exactly what I just did. Just wanted an inbuilt solution first.

Comment: @Sagar with BigInteger values? I really wanna see that

Comment: you'll have ro convert from BigDecimal to BigInteger ya know....because in most cases the number will not be a proper integer. And even 1.0 is not an integer. Though I know you know that but that's the case

Comment: Then it's either I have misinterpreted that symbol, or there's another meaning to it which I am not aware of yet

Comment: It seems i'm at fault. I was using the normal int and doubles. My bad. However there are many helper classes of bigdecimal which you could chain it to get the desired results. and also many posts similar to yours. Since I am not sure what exactly would match your needs hence I am not posting any supporting links to it.

Comment: @Sagar am reading on partially blind signature schemes, and in one scheme, that formula above is part of the overall function. It makes the whole idea of encryption take on a different meaning to me since it introduces decimals whereas, unless am not aware, encryption schemes use only integer values.

Comment: You can use commons math BigFraction class: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/BigFraction.html#pow(long)